# How to pass null parameters to a function

Tags: c

```
int val(){
   int  value;

   do{
      printf("Enter a value (between 1 & 5): ");
      scanf("%d", &value);
      if (value < 1 || value > 5){
        printf("*Error!!! Try again.\n");
      }
      else{
         printf("Thank You!\n");
      }
   } while (value < 1 || value > 5);
   return value;
}

int main(){
  int ran, value1;
  ran= (rand()% 50)+1;
  value1=val();
  return 0;
}
```

The function "val" is used to validate user's input.
I want to create another function and call it in main():

```
void displayNum(int n, int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth)
```

If user enters 2, `displayNum` prints "first" and "second". If user enters 5, displayNum prints "first", "second", ..."fifth".

Notes: "first", "second",..."fifth" are numbers generated by rand(). "int n" is value from the "val" function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void displayNum(int n, int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth){
    switch(n){
        case 5:printf("%d", fifth);
        case 4:printf("%d", fourth);
        case 3:printf("%d", third);
        case 2:printf("%d", second);
        case 1:
            printf("%d", first);
            break;
        default: printf("wrong n value\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But how can you pass value1 to displayNum?

Comment: You can call the function with `displayNum(value1, firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue, fourthValue, fifthValue);` inside `main()`.

Comment: What if user wants 3?. I don't think it still works if I do like this:
`displayNum(value1, firstValue, secondValue, thirdvalue);`

Comment: If n is equal to 3, the function will print third, second and first, and therefore it doesn't matter what value you give to the fourth and fifth arguments
EDIT: it will not work as such: displayNum(value1, firstValue, secondValue, thirdvalue). Try instead displayNum(value1, firstValue, secondValue, thirdvalue, 0, 0)

Comment: Do you know how to make `rand()` display different numbers? I put `displayNum(value1, ran, ran, ran);` and got the same number @@

Comment: @UserFriendly ,add `srand(time(NULL))` at the start of `main`

Comment: @UserFriendly , try `displaynum(value1,rand()%50+1,rand()%50+1,rand()%50+1)` . This is because `ran` holds 1 random number at one time and passing it will pass the same values itself

Comment: `if (value1 == 5){
      displayNum(value1, ran, ran, ran, ran, ran);
   }
   else if (value1 == 4){
      displayNum(value1, ran, ran, ran, ran, 0);
   }
   else if (value1 == 3){
      displayNum(value1, ran, ran, ran, 0, 0);
   }
   else if (value1 == 2){
      displayNum(value1, ran, ran, 0, 0, 0);
   }
   else if (value1 == 1){
      displayNum(value1, ran, 0, 0, 0, 0);
   }`

Comment: @UserFriendly ,`ran` can hold one value at a time .

Comment: I see. Thanks. It works. But i'm wondering if there is any other more efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explore a different avenue, you could use a variadic function:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void displayNum( int n, ... )
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start( ap, n );
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    int value = va_arg( ap, int );
    printf( "%20s: %d\n", label( i+1 ), value );
  }
  va_end( ap );
  printf( "\n" );
}
```

where `label` is a function that will print out the proper label based on the value of `i`.

This way you don't have to pass fixed number of parameters; if you only want to display one value, you'd call it as

```
displayNum( 1, first );
```

If you want to display 3 values, you'd call it as

```
displayNum( 3, first, second, third );
```

The first argument `n` is fixed and must always be present.  The remaining arguments are read based on the value of the first argument.  If you pass a 1, `displayNum` will only read and display the first additional argument.  If you pass a 3, `displayNum` will expect there to be *at least* three additional integer arguments on the stack.

Caveats: variadic functions are not type safe and the compiler will not warn you when you're passing arguments of the wrong type, nor will it alert you if you're passing too few or too many additional arguments.  If you call it as `displayNum( 1, "this is a test" );`, you'll either crash or get garbled output.

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *label( int n )
{
  const char *units[] = { "zeroth", "first", "second", "third", 
                          "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", 
                          "eighth", "ninth" };
  const char *teens[] = { "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth", "thirteenth", 
                          "fourteenth", "fifteenth", "sixteenth",
                          "seventeenth", "eighteenth", "ninteenth" };
  const char *decades[] = { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", 
                            "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

  static char buf[256] = {0};

  if ( n < 10 )
    return units[n];
  else if ( n < 20 )
    return teens[n-10];
  else
  {
    int t = n / 10;
    int u = n % 10;
    sprintf( buf, "%s", decades[t] );
    if ( u > 0 )
    {
      strcat( buf, "-" );
      strcat( buf, units[u] );
    }
    else
    {
      buf[ strlen(buf) - 1 ] = 0;
      strcat( buf, "ieth" );
    }
    return buf;
  }

  return "";
}

void displayNum( int n, ... )
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start( ap, n );
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    int value = va_arg( ap, int );
    printf( "%20s: %d\n", label( i+1 ), value );
  }
  printf( "\n" );
  va_end( ap );
}

int main( void )
{
  displayNum( 1, 1 );
  displayNum( 2, 1, 2 );
  displayNum( 3, 1, 2, 3 );
  displayNum( 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 );
  displayNum( 25, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25 );
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/stdarg: ./mystdarg
               first: 1

               first: 1
              second: 2

               first: 1
              second: 2
               third: 3

               first: 1
              second: 2
               third: 3
              fourth: 4
               fifth: 5
               sixth: 6
             seventh: 7
              eighth: 8
               ninth: 9
               tenth: 10

               first: 1
              second: 2
               third: 3
              fourth: 4
               fifth: 5
               sixth: 6
             seventh: 7
              eighth: 8
               ninth: 9
               tenth: 10
            eleventh: 11
             twelfth: 12
          thirteenth: 13
          fourteenth: 14
           fifteenth: 15
           sixteenth: 16
         seventeenth: 17
          eighteenth: 18
           ninteenth: 19
           twentieth: 20
        twenty-first: 21
       twenty-second: 22
        twenty-third: 23
       twenty-fourth: 24
        twenty-fifth: 25
```

As written, the `label` function will only handle inputs up to 99, after which you'll get some funny output.  The C language standard guarantees *at least* 127 arguments in a single function call, but you really don't want to do that.

**EDIT**

Or you could avoid all this nonsense and pass your values in an array, which is the better approach if all the values are of the same type:

```
void displayNum( int n, const int *values )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    printf( "%20s: %d\n", label( i + 1 ), values[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void displayNum(int n, int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth){
     int temp=1;
     while(n>=temp){
         if(temp==5)
            printf("%d ", fifth);

         elseif(temp==4)
            printf("%d ", fourth);

         elseif(temp==3)
            printf("%d ", third);

         else if(temp==2)
            printf("%d ", second);

         else if(temp==1)
            printf("%d", first);

          temp++;

      }

}
```